# Numbers in quotes read as numerical variable in R

Tags: r, string, import, read.table

I have a dataset where there are many columns with numbers in quotes which indicates that a variable is a factor. (ex: "8").

`read.table` automatically converts them in numerical variables even if `stringsAsFactor` is set as true.
Suppose I cannot convert them manually with `as.factor`, how can I import this dataset with those variables coded directly as factor?

Comment: In your `read.table` statement, you can specify the column class with the `colClasses` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the `quote` option. Set `quote=""`. Example:

```
t <- '"1" "3"
"2" "4"'
```

---

```
> str(read.table(text=t))
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: int  1 2
 $ V2: int  3 4
> str(read.table(text=t, quote=""))
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 2 levels "\"1\"","\"2\"": 1 2
 $ V2: Factor w/ 2 levels "\"3\"","\"4\"": 1 2
```

Comment: It works but the levels are coded like your example. Can you please explain why it happens and if this problem can be solved?

Comment: I've worked it out : `chars <- unlist(lapply(data, is.character))  ;
data = as.data.frame(sapply(data[,chars], function(x) gsub("\"", "", x)))`

Comment: Ah you mean there are double quotes ?

Comment: Actually my output was like `chr  "\"1\"" "\"1\"" "\"1\"" "\"1\""` and I had to convert them to factor to obtain `Factor w/ 3 levels "\"0\"","\"1\""`. Using the code above, I managed to have factors coded with `Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2",`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant double quotes. I understand that the 'problem' with factor coding was due to the double quoting, but I still find the behavior curious because even with `quote==""` the columns with numbers in quotes are not automatically converted in factor